# How to erase image specific areas by dragging the mouse in python GUI?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, user-interface

I want to use some python libraries to create a GUI app with which I can smear some area by dragging the mouse?
I am truly faithfully to thank anyone who can give me a hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most graphic libraries should capture the mouse pointer. Specifically I recommend [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro), which is very powerful, and you can access many things at the level of widgets. All the documentation can be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/)